# Why shouldn't we write validation checks in different if statements in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

```
function printAll(strs: string | string[] | null) {
  // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  //  DON'T DO THIS!
  //   KEEP READING
  // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  if (strs) {
    if (typeof strs === "object") {
      for (const s of strs) {
        console.log(s);
      }
    } else if (typeof strs === "string") {
      console.log(strs);
    }
  }
}
```

> We wrapped the entire body of the function in a truthy check, but this
> has a subtle downside: we may no longer be handling the empty string
> case correctly.
>
> TypeScript doesn’t hurt us here at all, but this is behavior worth
> noting if you’re less familiar with JavaScript. TypeScript can often
> help you catch bugs early on, but if you choose to do nothing with a
> value, there’s only so much that it can do without being overly
> prescriptive. If you want, you can make sure you handle situations
> like these with a linter.

It seems to be more readable. Why is Typescript saying that we shouldn't check for the null states in different if statements?

I didn't understand their explanations.
Please explain.

Comment: If `strs` is the empty string ( `""` ), the `if` test will fail and the empty string will not be logged. Better to do `if (strs != null)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already written in the paragraph you quoted:

> but this has a subtle downside: we may no longer be handling the empty string case correctly

I.e. if `str === ''` this code won't execute the body of the `if` because `if ('')` is a falsy. This *may* be ok, if the check is ensure, that your string is not empty. But this *may* also be an error, if you need to treat the empty string same as any longer string, but just treat `null` or `undefined` (so called "nullish" values) differently. That strongly depends on the situation, where you are using this check.

```
let str = '';
if (str) {
   //this won't be executed because '' is a falsy
}
```

You can separate `null` and `undefined` from the empty string `''` with the `typeof` operator

```
let str = '';
if (typeof str === "string") {
  //this will be executed
}


let str = null;
if (typeof str === "string") {
  //this won't be executed, because typeof null == "object"
}


let str = undefined;
if (typeof str === "string") {
  //this won't be executed, because typeof null == "undefined"
}
```

When using a newer version of JS you can also make use of the [optional chaining operator ?.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to separate `null` and `undefined` from the empty string `''` in one statement

```
let str = '';
if (str?.length >= 0) {
  //this will be executed, because ''.length == 0 and 0 >= 0 is true
}


let str = null;
if (str?.length >= 0) {
  //this won't be executed, because null?.length == undefined and 
  //undefined >= 0 is false
}


let str = undefined;
if (str?.length >= 0) {
  //this won't be executed, because undefined?.length == undefined and 
  //undefined >= 0 is false
}
```

On the other hand, if you don't use `?.` and just check `str.length` this will throw an error if `str` is `null` or `undefined`

```
let str = '';
if (str.length >= 0) {
  //this will be executed, because ''.length == 0 and 0 >= 0 is true
}


let str = null;
if (str.length >= 0) {
   //this will throw an error "cannot read property length of null"
}


let str = undefined;
if (str.length >= 0) {
   //this will throw an error "cannot read property length of undefined"    
}
```